# javascript event when a row is updated/changed in a Datasheet view?

Tags: 2010, javascript, event-receivers, datasheet, events

Is there any way to catch update/changes in the Datasheet view of a list in JavaScript in SharePoint 2010? I see their are event receivers but nothing in Javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The datasheet view was renamed to quick edit in SP2013, removing the ActiveX dependencies and migrating the implementation to html / js.

There is almost no documentation about what you are trying to achieve, but I would give a try to spjeff implementation, who overrides the template implementation:

http://www.spjeff.com/2014/05/17/quick-edit-supports-js-link-and-client-side-rendering/

Comment: Sorry. I forgot to mention I need this for SharePoint 2010.

Comment: Then I'm sorry too, because in SP 2010 the datasheet view is an ActiveX control, and there is no way you can attach a js event to it: [take a look at this](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2f2990b2-9dff-4fd0-ab5b-bc6b082fa558/add-validations-using-javascriptjquery-to-datasheet-view)

Answer (score 0):

**Note:**

in June 2017, Microsoft disabled the use of JavaScript in a Calculated Column

That means given answers may not apply  for newer SharePoint versions

For long explanation and work arounds see:
[June 13th 2017 Microsoft blocked handling HTML markup in SharePoint calculated fields - how to get the same functionality back](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/218102/june-13th-2017-microsoft-blocked-handling-html-markup-in-sharepoint-calculated-f/218110#218110)

---

**Original answer:**

http://www.viewmaster365.com/#/Create/SearchFilter

This kinda weird looking code in a Calculated Column set to datatype is Number will attach a KeyUp event to a DOM element above the search box, that way catching each keyup event. If you attach it to each TR (TableRow leave out the 3 parentNodes), it should work in a Datasheet View as well.

```
    =" <img src=""_layouts/images/blank.gif"" onload=""{"
     & "var TR=this;while(TR.tagName!='TR'){TR=TR.parentNode}"
     & "TR.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.addEventListener('keyup',"
     & "(function(keyevent){"
     & "this.style.backgroundColor='"
     & [Task Name]  & "'.indexOf(keyevent.srcElement.value)===-1"
     & "?'lightcoral':'lightgreen'"
     & "})"
     & ".bind(TR))"
     & "}"">"
```

[image]

ICC

Comment: Sorry. I forgot to mention I need this for SharePoint 2010.

Comment: SharePoint 2010 accepts this HTML/Javascript in Calculated Columns