# How can I filter a List View in a Web Part page using AJAX so the entire page doesn't reload/refresh?

Tags: 2010, web-part, list-view, filter

I have a Web Part page with a list view. I know how to use filter webparts that connect to the list view to filter the list. But those all reload/refresh the entire page. I was wondering if there is anyway to do it using AJAX?

So say I have a list with a date field. I want to be able to filter/reload just the list view for rows where the date is equal to some value I provide.

Comment: Use inplviewhash for this.

Comment: @Akhoy: Does this work for 2010? Everything I read says for 2013.

Comment: Nope won't work for 2010. This is just for 2013.

Comment: Didn't see the 2010 tag. Apologies.

Comment: possible duplicate of [javascript event when a row is updated/changed in a Datasheet view?](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/154100/javascript-event-when-a-row-is-updated-changed-in-a-datasheet-view)

Comment: @DannyEngelman: Those are two different questions/unrelated sir.Thanks!